# Serialize and deserialize object flattened

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have 2 classes:

```
public class SomeClass {
  private AnotherClass anotherClass;
  private String astring;
}

public class AnotherClass {

   private Date field1;
   private String field2;
}
```

I need to serialize and deserialize objects of SomeClass and would like the json to look like

```
someClass {
  field1: field1Value;
  field2: field2Value;
  astring: astringvalue;
}
```

i.e. flatten the fields in `AnotherClass`.

I know I can use the @JsonUnwrapped annotation like this

```
  public class SomeClass {
      @JsonUnwrapped
      private AnotherClass anotherClass;
      private String astring;
    }
```

to accomplish this but since `anotherClass` appears in many classes I would rather avoid adding this annotation to each of those classes.

Is there a way to achieve this flattening through a customer serializer & deserializer applied to  `AnotherClass`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mixin to apply the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation to all classes

```
public abstract class FlattenMixin {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private AnotherClass anotherClass;

}
```

Then use a mixinResolver to apply to all classes.

```
    objectMapper.setMixInResolver(new MixInResolver() {

        @Override
        public Class<?> findMixInClassFor(Class<?> cls) {
            // maybe filter to specific package ?
            return FlattenMixin.class;
        }

        @Override
        public MixInResolver copy() {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where would the mixinResolver live in? In AnotherClass?

Comment: The example here creates it inline. You could have a new class for the mixinresolver. I don't think AnotherClass would be a good place to put it. You may want to add a bit of logic to restrict which classes you add the mixin to. If all your classes which have a reference to `anotherclass` are in the same package, then check the package name before adding the mixin.

Comment: Inline where? In some test class? The classes that use anotherclass live in many different packages (which I dont have control over) so I probably can not filter. If I created another class for the mixinresolver, the classes that use anotherClass would somehow have to implement/extend that class?

Comment: You just need to add the resolver to the jackson objectMapper being used to do the serialize/deserialize. You don't specify in your question how you are calling the objectmapper, so I can't say exactly how you need to do this.

Comment: I am not calling the objectmapper directly. Typically serialization/deserialization happens through rest calls using jax-rs. jax-rs and jackson then interact without me doing anything (and must be using the default objectmapper). I probably have to get a handle of the objectMapper and register the serialization/deserialization behavior I want for anotherClass.

Comment: yep, that sounds about right. I'm not familiar with configuring Jackson for jax-rs.